# how do I change default editor value in MOODLE using formslib?

Tags: moodle

Here's the formslib moodle doc:

```
$mform->addElement('editor', 'fieldname', get_string('labeltext', 'langfile'));
```

And this is supposed to be the 4th attribute parameter:

```
array(
    'subdirs'=>0,
    'maxbytes'=>0,
    'maxfiles'=>0,
    'changeformat'=>0,
    'context'=>null,
    'noclean'=>0,
    'trusttext'=>0);
)
```

I tried:

```
$mform->addElement('editor', 'fieldname', get_string('labeltext', 'langfile'), array('context'=>'test"));
```

but doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I copied your example code into the forum module as a test (mod/forum/post_form.php) in Moodle 2.0 and managed to get an editor to display using the following:

```
$forum_id = optional_param('forum', 0, PARAM_INT); // id of forum (from URL)

$cm = get_coursemodule_from_instance('forum', $forum_id, $course->id);
$context = get_context_instance(CONTEXT_MODULE, $cm->id);

$mform->addElement('editor', 'fieldname', get_string('labeltext', 'langfile'), null, array('context' => $context) );
```

It's crucial to specify module context for form editor elements.  Also, the fourth argument is reserved  - you should use the fifth argument for setting context and other variables, although I believe both arguments actually work (!)

The form will now have <textarea id="id_fieldname"> using the example code above.

If you want to specify a default value for the editor before the user has even input anything, you can use setValue() as a method call to the result of addElement():

```
$mform->addElement
(
   'editor',
   'fieldname',
   get_string('labeltext', 'langfile'),
   null,
   array('context' => $context)
)->setValue( array('text' => 'Default text!') );
```

I hope this answers your question - but please comment if there's anything specific I can help with here.

Answer (score 1):

```
$mform->addElement('editor', 'fieldname', get_string('labeltext', 'langfile'),
        array('context'=>'test"));
```

You have a syntax error in the above line :D **`'test'`**, not **`'test"`**